# Strange behaviour of operator [] in stl::map

Tags: c++, c++11

i was solving a program to prevent duplicate values on map, i have written the following program

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 */
#include <map>
#include <limits>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



template<typename K, typename V>

class interval_map {
    std::map<K,V> m_map;

public:
    // constructor associates whole range of K with val by inserting (K_min, val)
    // into the map
    interval_map( V const& val) {
        m_map.insert(m_map.end(),std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<K>::lowest(),val));
    }

    void assign( K const& keyBegin, K const& keyEnd, V const& val ) {
        if (!(keyBegin < keyEnd)) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (m_map.rbegin() != m_map.rend()) { 
                //get the previous key value
                auto prev_value = m_map.rbegin()->second;
                //compare with current value
                if (prev_value == val) {
                    cout << "duplicate";
                    //duplicate entry values are restricted, do nothing     
                }
                else {
                    for (auto i = keyBegin; i<keyEnd; i++) {
                        cout << i << endl;
                        m_map[i] = val;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // look-up of the value associated with key
    V const& operator[]( K const& key ) const {
        return ( --m_map.upper_bound(key) )->second;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    interval_map<unsigned int,char> test('m');
    test.assign(2,4,'k');
    test.assign(4,7, 'k');
    cout << test[5];

    return 0;
}
```

the cout << test[5] returns k even though it not assigned to map before.How is it possible, did i do anything wrong , or is this the default behaviour of operand [] ? The above program creates keys with in intervals and assign the same value to them.For example test.assign(2,4, 'k') creates keys from to 2,3 and assign the value k to it.The idea is to prevent duplication of the values between keys generated by consecutive assign method.

Comment: 5 is *in the interval* `4-7`, which you previously assigned. So what did you expect to get?

Comment: BTW, I this looks like a personal assignment (possibly as part of an interview). Doesn't seem entirely ethical to go on SO with this.

Comment: but 4-7 interval has same value of before assign method call, so the intervals wont be assigned.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you meant to say. If you refer to `2-4` as the "before", then `4-7` does not intersect it. By your own explanation `2,4` is half open. I.e 4 is not inclusive.

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: sorry, it was my first time at this site.So let me explain The first assign call create keys up to 3 excluding the 4.The second assign call checks whether last key of first assign call, i.e 3 has same value of the second assign call. like if (m_map[3] == value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> did i do anything wrong

Maybe. It depends on what you intended to do.

`std::map::upper_bound` which your `operator[]` uses looks for an element with a *greater* key than the operand. Your map doesn't contain any keys greater than 5<sup>†</sup>, so that operation returns the end iterator.

Your `operator[]` then decrements the iterator, which in the case of end iterator results in an iterator to the last element. The last element in your map is the key-value pair `3, k` and so `k` is returned.

---

<sup>†</sup> Because as you explained, the `test.assign(4,7, 'k')` call does nothing.

Comment: it was a typo, i meant to ask "did i do anything wrong", what i couldnt understand is it assigns the key 5 to the map, but it returns the value as k (but i didnt assign any value to 5)

Comment: @manman it turns out that you did assign a value to the key 5.

Comment: but there is a if loop which checks if the value is equal to the value of last key created by previous assign call, may be it failed to do it

Comment: @manman I see. You should explain in the question what your program does in more detail.

Comment: perfect, sorry couldnt give the upvote point since  i am new and it says like 15 points required to upvote.Thanks this was the point i got stuck.So the m_map[5] does not exist until it is called.